# Trouble using Jackson (JsonNode) to parse nested paths?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Trying to use Jackson to parse JSON. Simple enough- I'm clearly messing up something basic.

```
final JsonNode root = objectMapper.readTree(res.payload().asUtf8String());
JsonNode body = root.path("body");
JsonNode message = root.path("body").path("errorMessage");
logger.log(Level.INFO, body.asText());
logger.log(Level.INFO, message.asText());
```

**Expected Result:**

```
INFO: {"errorMessage": "input is not a string"}
INFO: "input is not a string"
```

**Actual Result:**

```
INFO: {"errorMessage": "input is not a string"}
INFO:
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was because my nested value was, itself, escaped.

debugging `root` gave something of this form

```
{
  status: 400,
  headers: {...},
  body: "{\"errorMessage\":\"input is not a string\"}"
}
```

The strategy then was to use the `objectMapper` again

```
final JsonNode root = objectMapper.readTree(res.payload().asUtf8String());
// Body is, itself, escaped so we need to re-parse
JsonNode body = objectMapper.readTree(root.path("body").asText());
```